# Can some one have a look at my code? error C2059: syntax error : 'public'

Tags: c++

I am writing an algebra tree program. While compiling, I got a lot of errors. I do not know where the errors come from.

Here is my code:

```
//file: Term.h
#ifndef TERM
#define TERM
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Term {
public:
  Term() {}
  virtual ~Term() {}
  virtual string symbolicEval() = 0;
  virtual double numericalEval(double X) = 0;
};  
 #endif

//file: UnaryOp.h
#ifndef UNARYOP
#define UNARYOP
#include "Term.h";

class UnaryOp: public Term{
protected:
   Term* Child;
public:
   UnaryOp(Term* l){Child = l;};
   virtual ~UnaryOp(){delete Child;};
   virtual string symbolicEval(){};
  virtual double numericalEval(){};

};
#endif UNARYOP

//file:CCos.h
#ifndef COS_H
#define COS_H

 #include "UnaryOp.h"

 class  Cos: public UnaryOp{
  public:
    Cos(Term * l):UnaryOp(l){};
    virtual ~ Cos(){};
    virtual string symbolicEval(){
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "cos(x)" << endl;
    return oss.str();
  };
    virtual double numericalEval(double X){
    return cos(Child->numericalEval(X));
  }

  }
  #endif COS_H
```

While compiling, I got the following errors:

```
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\unaryop.h(3): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2236: unexpected 'class' 'Cos'. Did you forget a ';'?
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2059: syntax error : ':'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2059: syntax error : 'public'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\ccos.h(6): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\administrator\desktop\algebra\algebra\algebra.cpp(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Cos'
```

Can someone give me a hint where am I wrong?

Comment: Never put `using namespace std;` in a header. Never, ever, ever, **ever.**

Comment: The "did you forget a ';'?" message is relevant. You have no ';' on the end of class Cos.

Comment: @chhowie, hi, thanks for replying. Why never put `using namespace std;` in a header?

Comment: @JessicaJin Because it brings in the names of every type in the `std` namespace not just into the scope of your header, but into the scope of *every file that includes this header, **including other headers***, cascading. And maybe whoever includes any of these headers doesn't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with replacing

```
#include "Term.h";
```

by

```
#include "Term.h"
```

(there may be more things wrong). And actually, the first error message exactly told you that the preprocessor was expecting a newline where you wrote a semicolon, so next time please read the error messages first.

Comment: that will not break the compilation, I think

Comment: @Doc Brown, Hi! thanks for replying... I am almost frustrated since this the first time I wrote such a big project...

Comment: @AliKazmi: don't argue with the compiler, instead read the messages.

Comment: I mean, in this case only

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things.

Why are you providing the definition for methods in header files?

```
//file:CCos.h
#ifndef COS_H
#define COS_H

 #include "UnaryOp.h"

 class  Cos: public UnaryOp{
  public:
    Cos(Term * l):UnaryOp(l){};
    virtual ~ Cos(){};
    virtual string symbolicEval(){
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "cos(x)" << endl;
    return oss.str();
  };
    virtual double numericalEval(double X){
    return cos(Child->numericalEval(X));
  }

  }
  #endif COS_H
```

If you are using the "{}" after a method declaration in a ".H" file, would you please explain what does that mean? 
How does a compiler understands it?

When do you use a colon? Is it after a method declaration or after a definition or for bothboth?

Are .h files compiled? why? why not?

If you could answer these, you have your answer. It is more of a homework. Request you to please post only relevant & only those questions, for which you need technical assistance.

Answer (score -2):

you are missing closing brace of  virtual string symbolicEval() function.

Comment: Nope. The indentation is misleading, but it's there.

Comment: I was talking about class  Cos::virtual string symbolicEval(); Its upto questioner, cant say anything

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say. The braces in the `Cos` class are balanced. There is a misplaced `;` but that's not what you said.

Comment: The misplaced ; will cause end of class, wont it?

Comment: @AliKazmi No, the misplaced ; will not cause the end of the class. You need a closing } to do that.

Comment: No, it will not "cause end of class". There needs to be a `;` at the end of the class, but a semicolon after a method doesn't hurt anything.